# cannot install MbedTLS packages in Julia

Tags: julia, stack-overflow, mbedtls

I have trouble importing the only "MbedTLS" package from the web to Julia. It is required for using Julia in the Jupyter notebook. I've acquired its zipped file from the git

> https://github.com/JuliaWeb/MbedTLSBuilder/releases

However, I don't know how to install this successfully to Julia. Could you help me?
The error message is 
`"security protocol somthing..."` and `"LoadError : Could not download https://github.com/quinnj/MbedTLSBuilder/releases/download/v0.6/MbedTLS.x86_64-w64-ming32.tar.gz to C:\Users\MYNAME\.julia\v0.6\Mbed"`

Furthermore, I reinstalled `"IJulia"` and then, it appears `"stackoverflow"` error. what is wrong with this procedure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer at

```
https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/issues/456
```

and download and install `"cmake"`

Comment: a)downloaded MbedTLS.jl package, unzipped to ...stdlib/v1.1/MbedTLS b) installed cmake-2.8.12-2.el7.x86_64.rpm and mbedtls-2.7.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and invoking julia>using ECharts. I am getting error "MbedTLS".  Could you please guide me in installing package MbedTLS!